# PHP decrypt with key

Tags: php, encryption

I'm trying to decrypt with PHP but I don't know how to first start.

**for example**

secret text encrypt like this

```
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
```

**and key is like**

```
70f9ac9b5b692a236031023c67d5166e990f18bd6ec89061
```

This original key is bin file and I try to convert it with `bin2hex()`

What's kind of this encrypt method ?

Addition info

the decrypt code which from java

```
public class b
{
  public static String a(String paramString, byte[] paramArrayOfByte)
  {
    try
    {
      SecretKeySpec localSecretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(paramArrayOfByte, "DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
      Cipher localCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede");
      localCipher.init(1, localSecretKeySpec);
      String str = new String(Base64.encode(localCipher.doFinal(ab.b(paramString)), 0));
      return str;
    }
    catch (Exception localException)
    {
      return null;
    }
    catch (NoSuchPaddingException localNoSuchPaddingException)
    {
      break label52;
    }
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException localNoSuchAlgorithmException)
    {
      label52:
      break label52;
    }
  }

  public static byte[] a(byte[] paramArrayOfByte1, byte[] paramArrayOfByte2, byte[] paramArrayOfByte3)
  {
    if ((paramArrayOfByte1 == null) || (paramArrayOfByte2 == null) || (paramArrayOfByte3 == null)) {
      return null;
    }
    try
    {
      SecretKeySpec localSecretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(paramArrayOfByte2, "AES");
      String str = "NoPadding";
      if (paramArrayOfByte3.length % 188 != 0) {
        str = "PKCS5Padding";
      }
      Cipher localCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/" + str);
      localCipher.init(2, localSecretKeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(paramArrayOfByte1, 0, paramArrayOfByte1.length));
      byte[] arrayOfByte = localCipher.doFinal(paramArrayOfByte3);
      return arrayOfByte;
    }
    catch (Exception localException)
    {
      d.e("m3u8", localException.toString());
    }
    return null;
  }

  public static String b(String paramString, byte[] paramArrayOfByte)
  {
    try
    {
      SecretKeySpec localSecretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(paramArrayOfByte, "DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
      Cipher localCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede");
      localCipher.init(2, localSecretKeySpec);
      String str = ab.b(localCipher.doFinal(Base64.decode(paramString, 0)));
      return str;
    }
    catch (Exception localException)
    {
      return null;
    }
    catch (NoSuchPaddingException localNoSuchPaddingException)
    {
      break label45;
    }
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException localNoSuchAlgorithmException)
    {
      label45:
      break label45;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you know the encryption algorithm used? If you don't then you won't be able to decrypt it.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from source code of java file.
Encryption used here is TripleDES or DESede.

First of all you see above output is encoded with base64.

As you wrote key is also encrypted with bin2hex(),
By making or using public released sources you can make PHP decryptor for TripleDES

Here is idea of function:

```
function Decrypt($data, $secret)
{

    //Generate a key from a hash
    $key = md5(utf8_encode($secret), true);

    //Take first 8 bytes of $key and append them to the end of $key.
    $key .= substr($key, 0, 8);

    $data = base64_decode($data);

    $data = mcrypt_decrypt('tripledes', $key, $data, 'ecb');

    $block = mcrypt_get_block_size('tripledes', 'ecb');
    $len = strlen($data);
    $pad = ord($data[$len-1]);

    return substr($data, 0, strlen($data) - $pad);
}
```

I hope this helps for you :)

Comment: Hello as you can see above code does not decrypt key which is bin2hex codded you first must create method to decrypt key from hex :) this is basic tripledes decryption :)

Comment: I searched for many days I found only the way to convert bin2hex or hex2bin what's kind of another decrypt you mean ?